# NSFetchedResultsController not reloading sections after update data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have `UITableView` with results from `NSFetchedResultsController` grouped by date attribute in sections(today, tomorrow and etc). On the background thread I update `CoreData` entity(change day), and call on the main thread `[self.tableView reloadData]`, but table not grouped in sections by new dates, it is working only after reloading application. Where I am wrong?

Comment: You should post some code for update/reload data. Also for reloading the table, you should first call a method that fetch the new data from CD and after that call [tableView reloadData];

Comment: Are you the delegate of the FRC and are you merging the saved changes to the main context?

Comment: If you're updating core data objects in background threads and expecting to see changes in the main thread, make sure you know what you're doing. This is a good article to read (http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/)